# How to override item list creation in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to create a custom list using the simple_list_item_1 layout so that I can change the font, background, etc. How do you go about doing this?

I tried overriding `getView` by using a custom adapter extending `ArrayAdapter`, but whenever I do something to the list (e.g. search), the generated list loses all customization until I minimise the keyboard. That's why I thought it would be better if I could override the list creation method in the first place.

Here is the custom adapter class

```
public class AlphabeticalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements SectionIndexer {
private HashMap<String, Integer> _alphaIndexer;
private String[] _sections;
private Typeface _typeface;

public AlphabeticalAdapter(Context c, int resource, List<String> data) {
    // create ArrayAdapter<String>
    super(c, resource, data);

    try {
        // generate typeface
        _typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/hs_bold.otf");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
    return _alphaIndexer.get(_sections[section]);
}

public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    return 1;
}

public Object[] getSections() {
    return _sections;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView text = (TextView) convertView;

    if (text != null) {
        text.setTypeface(_typeface);
    }

    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

}

Comment: "How do you go about doing this?" -- step #1: Copy the `simple_list_item_1` layout into your project and modify it to suit. You will find copies of this layout in your Android SDK installation. Step #2: Use your revised layout in your `ArrayAdapter` constructor. Step #3: If you want to have dynamic effects, based on model data, override `getView()` and modify the row widgets as needed. Just make sure that you *always* modify the row widgets, as rows get recycled, and so you do not necessarily know what the starting state of your widgets are.

Comment: "but whenever I do something to the list (e.g. search), the generated list loses all customization until I minimise the keyboard" -- 
presumably there is a bug in your `getView()` implementation. We cannot help you much with that, as your question does not contain your `getView()` code, let alone any description of exactly what customization is lost. Feel free to edit your question and add that sort of stuff if you want specific help. Screenshots would also be useful, but you may need to upload those elsewhere and link to them here, as you may not have the rep to upload images directly.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added the custom adapter class. Basically when I load the activity (and populate the list), there is a brief moment where the list is unformatted. It takes a split-second before any formatting gets done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting myself from my comment:

> Step #3: If you want to have dynamic effects, based on model data, override getView() and modify the row widgets as needed. Just make sure that you always modify the row widgets, as rows get recycled, and so you do not necessarily know what the starting state of your widgets are.

In your case, you are not always tailoring the widgets on every `getView()` call. You are only doing so when `convertView` is not `null`. `convertView` will be `null` when you are initially populating your `ListView`.

The following implementation always calls `setTypeface()`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView text=(TextView)super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    text.setTypeface(_typeface);

    return(text);
}
```

Now, I have not examined the impacts of calling `setTypeface()`. Ideally, it is cheap, and so just calling it every time is OK. If, OTOH, profiling suggests that calling `setTypeface()` every time is adding too much overhead, then you can look to optimize matters. In particular, in this case, you want to use the same typeface for every row -- it is not varying based upon which row you are rendering. In that case, you only need to call `setTypeface()` on `getView()` calls where a new `TextView` is created, and that *should* be in the cases where `convertView` is `null`. So, the following has less overhead but is riskier, as you are making some assumptions about the implementation of your superclass:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView text=(TextView)super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    if (convertView==null) {
        text.setTypeface(_typeface); // because a new TextView definitely was created, since we could not reuse the convertView as it was null
    }

    return(text);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. Actually, I followed your first suggestion (finding the actual layout file and modifying it) before seeing your answer and it worked perfectly. Still, your answer here also answers my question. This would be useful for dynamic additions.